# Set Twig object property name using variable

Tags: object, properties, twig

I need to set an object property name dynamically in Twig:

```
{% set featureId = feature.id %}
{% set gridEnabled = gridEnabled|merge({featureId: true}) %}
```

But that sets `"featureId"` as a property of `gridEnabled`. Is there a way to tell Twig that `featureId` is a variable? I'm surprised it interprets that as a string without quotes.

Follow-up question: Here is the full set--I was able to further reduce to "feature.id". Can these lines be combined?

```
{% set gridEnabled = grid.enabled %}
{% set gridEnabled = gridEnabled|merge({(feature.id): true}) %}
{% set grid = grid|merge({'enabled':gridEnabled}) %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very easy actually,

```
{% set gridEnabled = gridEnabled|merge({(featureId): true}) %}
```

---

(edit) follow-up

```
{% set grid = grid | merge({'enabled' : (grid.enabled | merge({(featureId):1,}))}) %}
```

Comment: That's what I have above. It doesn't work---sets the property name to "featureId" ---oh wait, you have it in parens--that's it? Do you know the reason why that works?

Comment: Hence the 2 extra parentheses, this forces twig to first interpolate the variable

Comment: I added a follow-up, can that also be reduced?

Comment: thanks! --this helps me understand what twig needs to process first